# Cookie is present in browser, but php $_COOKIE is empty

Tags: php, cookies

I have a project that works on a local server but not on my production server, due to cookies not being seen by the server. I've made a minimal version of the code that reproduces the issue on that server:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_COOKIE['foo'])){
    setcookie('foo', 'bar', time() + 7*24*60*60, '/');
    echo "Cookie was not found, so we just created it.";
} else {
    echo "Cookie was found!";
}

?>
```

No matter how many times I refresh this page, I always get the "not found" message. Whenever I try to log the `$_COOKIE` variable, I get an empty Array. However:

- The cookie is present in the browser, and correctly sent with the request
- The cookie is set and read in the same file (it's not an issue with the `path`)
- There is no output before `setcookie`, and the file is encoded in UTF8 without BOM

I think this is a server configuration issue, since the code works locally, but I have no idea where to look. Has anyone seen this before, do you know what could cause this?

If you need more info, just tell me and I'll add it to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Any CDN and/or caching server involved which swallows the cookie…?

Comment: Check your server's php.ini for the `variables_order` directive. Is the `C` missing from it? http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: @deceze There is a Varnish cache set up, but this page is not cached. Do you think that could swallow cookies? @Michael, thanks for your suggestion, I've checked, and it seems to be ok : `variables_order = EGPCS`

Comment: Cache servers often do not pass cookies through by default, unless you whitelist them explicitly.

Comment: @deceze I've talked to a colleague about Varnish, and he said the same thing as you: it filters cookies based on a whitelist. Thank you for your help, please post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I have the same issue. If I `var_dump($_COOKIE)` it shows `[]` with method POST (from a simple `data:text/html, <form method="post"...` page. Opening the same page with a direct hit (regular GET request) shows the cookies correctly. It worked fine with `method="put"`,  `method="delete"`, `method="get"`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's a cache server or CDN involved, it may be filtering cookies based on a whitelist. This is to improve caching, since each request with a unique set of cookies would need to be regarded as different from other requests and could not be cached (you may receive a different reply from the server based on your cookies, so the cache server cannot serve you the cached response of a previous client). Since lots of services are setting cookies which may be sent to the server (e.g. analytics packages) but have absolutely no influence on the contents of the response, heeding all cookies by default would often completely subvert caching.

Configure the caching server in charge to specifically pay attention to your cookie and to forward it to the origin server. If you have a lot of different cookies, consider giving them a common prefix and whitelist that (e.g. `foo-*`).

Comment: Good explanation. Also, thank you for the tip about the prefix, that may be helpful to me, to avoid asking my colleagues every time I need a new cookie.

Answer (score 6):

I just dealt with the same issue, my production server was allowing me to create a browser cookie using `setcookie('cookieNameHere', $cookieValueHere, time() + (86400 * 365), "/")`, but the `$_COOKIE` variable was always an empty array.

The issue was that my production server blocked direct access to the`$_COOKIE` variable contents via PHP for security reasons.

My solution was to access the cookie value via JavaScript using the following function:

```
    function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
      var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
          c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
      }
      return "";
    }
```

I continued to create/update the cookie via PHP.

FYI, I was working on a WordPress site hosted on WP-Engine. See [this page](https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/) for an in depth explanation, and for other options in the event you absolutely need to access a cookie value via PHP (ADMIN-AJAX calls, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem, and it turned out to be HAProxy configuration issue. Do you have any load balancer between the server and the user?

Comment: Thank you for your input, that might be the case, I'll ask my colleagues about that.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is the server time. Check your time with time() function and compare with local time. Maybe one of them is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have checked the time, and it is the same as my machine's